# Cannot assign "'1'": "Offers.state must be a "States" instance

Tags: python, django, forms, instance

I have read several answers to this same question, but none have worked for me. Here's my model:

```
class States(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    abrev = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.abrev

class Offers(models.Model):
     *other fields*
     state = models.ForeignKey(States on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

so in views i am doing this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        **other fields**
        state = States.objects.get(pk=request.POST['state'])
        Offers.objects.create(**other fields**, state=state)
    except Exception as e:
        print ("error in form")
```

But am always getting the same Error

> Cannot assign "'1'": "Offers.state must be a "States" instance.

And as you can see, i am passing an instance, not the id of the element. I use the id that comes from the form just to query the DB and find the instance with this: state = States.objects.get(pk=request.POST['state'])

The form works just fine, and I tried to do it with forms.py and if form.is_valid(), but got the exact same result.

am on:
django 3.2.3
python 3.9.2

EDIT**
It works in the django admin.

Comment: You're retyping code, rather than cutting-and-pasting.  Are you sure it looks exactly like that?

Comment: For example, if you actually had `state = request.POST['state']` / `slate = States.objects.get(pk=state)` (notice the typo), then you would get the results you describe.

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly like that, i didn't copy and paste because is way too much code.

Comment: what happens when you try: `Offers.objects.create(**other fields**, state_id=state)`. This is a great case to use a debugger and see what you have going on. Missing a comma in your ForeignKey by the way.

Comment: Hi @luisdaniel Is your problem solved ?

Comment: one more tip for you, wrap the try around just your offers.objects.create.

Comment: @AMG i get Cannot assign "'1'": "Offers.state must be a "States" instance. Where am i missing a comma?

Comment: @Mythilydevaraj nop, still the same issue.

Comment: @AMG you are right i will use the try just aroung offers.objects.create, didnt think about it! :D But it doesnt solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Offers.objects.create(**other fields**, state=state)

Here other fields is dict type contains all values to the model.

In the dict add

**other_fields["created_by"] = state**

or

**other_fields["created_by_id"] = state.id**

Then create,

Offers.objects.create(**other_fields)